# How I can validate if query have a list on Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, list, verify

I need to control the result of `query.list()`:

Case 1: Perfect. The user send a name of **one** Object that exist on the DB.

Case 2: Incorrect. The user send a name of **any** Object that exist on the BD.

Case 3: Fail. The system fail for another reason.

This is the my DAO function:

```
public MyObject function(String name) throws Exception {
    MyObject object = null;
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = NewHibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
    try {
        Query query = session.createQuery("from Object where name = '" + name + "'");
        if (query/*HELP ME!*/) {
            //Case 1:
            object = (MyObject) query.list().get(0);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        //Case 3:
        throw ex;
    } finally {
        transaction.commit();
        session.close();
    }
    //Case 2 (Oposite to case 1, then object is null)
    return object;
}
```

Help me please. The code has the message `HELP ME`. I din't know how verify the existence of `query.list()`

THANKS!!

Comment: Don't, ever, use string concatenation to pass parameters to a query. Use named parameters, as explained in the documentation. This is basic Java, and has nothing to do with Hibernate: `List<MyEntity> list = query.list(); if (list.size() == 1) ...`

Comment: Thank you! I had tried your solution in the past it doesn't work. Now yes!. Excuse me, inclusive I considered this as stupid question but not served me so obvious